# How do I setup different font styles using apple's typography guidelines for different screen sizes on React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile, font-size, styling, typography

I want to change font sizes depending on breakpoints globally through redux, what is the standard way to scale typography for different screen sizes for mobile apps.

Can someone please guide me whether this is font sizes changed in accessibility settings or these are guidelines for setting font sizes for different screen sizes ie: small, medium, etc

and if yes then what exactly what is the screen size of small device and which screen sizes are defined in small. I need a standard for all break points(screen sizes)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7okP8.png)

I have tried scaled metrics and changing font Sizes using the dimensions library in react native but my CTO is saying that it doesn't scale properly according to apple's guidelines

I used scaled metrics and changing font Sizes using the dimensions library in react native but it doesn't scale properly according to apple's guidelines.